# Not able to hit a HTTPS service via Classic ASP

Tags: asp.net, vba, web-services, https, asp-classic

I am trying to hit a HTTPS link via a Classic ASP Code. The service was accessible when it was in http but now both both service and Classic ASP code are hosted to HTTPS

I am using below code

```
    set objDom = createobject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    objDom.Open "GET", url, False
    objDom.setTimeouts 50000, 50000, 1000000, 1000000 'ms - resolve, connect, send, receive'
   'objDom.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic AUTH_STRING"
    objDom.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    objDom.setOption 2, 13056
    objDom.Send
```

I have already used objDom.setOption 2, 13056 to ignore certificate errors.
Still not able to connect to link

Comment: Your issues possibly relate to the move from http to https at the server rather than any settings in you code. Establish a connection to each via a web browser just to get some clarity on any web server settings that are interfering. If this is not possible then maybe Telerik Fiddler (free) or another web traffic viweer will give you some insight into exactly what is going on.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat We are able to view web service response when we hit the same from server browser. Hence simply means https link is working from server and hence no issue in accessing. Issue should be possibly with code. Bcz we are also able to hit same from javascript by Ajax call.

Comment: Just a thought. Is the service and the Classic ASP site on the same server? Is port 443 open on the firewall?

Comment: @MrSlim yes both service and Classic ASP are on same server. I will have to check on firewall for 443 port.  Any other help ??

Comment: What errors if any do you get?  What Version of Windows is the Server?